# Программа завершает свое выполнение после функции sprintf если ее компилировать через gcc, хотя через онлайн компилятор всё работает отлично

Tags: c

```c
int main()
{
    char mas[8][12]
    int i;

    printf(" 12345678\n");
    printf(" ________\n");

    for(i = 1; i < 9; i++) 
        sprintf(mas[i], "|OOOOOOOO|%i", i) 
 
    for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%s\n", mas[i]);
```

Не знаю из-за чего так происходит, программа полностью дописана и до этого в процессе все было хорошо и функция работала как надо

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Индексы массива нумеруются с нуля. В циклах `for(i=1;i<9;i++)` вы обращаетесь к несуществующей восьмой строке массива `mas`.

Comment: Ох. Даже стыдно стало, спасибо

Comment: мало точек с запятой, которые должны завершать команду. Код не будет компилироваться.